# Let $ F $ be a field. Show that all polynomials with constant term $ a_0 = 0 $ form an ideal $ \langle x \rangle $ of $ F \langle x \rangle $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

Let $ F $ be a field. Show that all constant polynomials $ a_0 = 0 $ form an ideal $ \langle x \rangle $ of $ F \langle x \rangle $.

**My Try:**

Let $ F $ be a field. Suppose $ \langle x \rangle =\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i $ with $a_0=0$ and $a_i\in F$. Let's prove that $\langle x\rangle $ form an ideal $ \langle x \rangle $ of $ F \langle x \rangle $. In fact, notice that $\langle x\rangle=\varnothing$. So,
$$\begin{align*}\left (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x^i \right )+\left ( \sum_{i=1}^n b_i x^i \right )&=\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i x^i+b_i x^i)\\ &=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i x^i. \end{align*}$$ Where $c_i=a_i+b_i\in F$. This shows that $ \langle x \rangle $ is closed under addition.

Clearly the polynomials $ 0 = \sum_ {i = 1} ^ n 0_i x ^ i \in \langle x \rangle $, and $ -\left (\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x^i\right )\in \langle x\rangle$.

Now,
$$\begin{align*}\left (\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^i \right )\left (\sum_{i=1}^n b_i x^i \right )&=\sum_{i=1}^n \left (\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_{n-i} \right )x^i\\ &=\sum_{i=1}^n (a_1b_{n-1}+a_2b_{n-2}+\cdots+a_{n-1}b_1)x^i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n d_ix^i. \end{align*}$$

Where $d_i=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_{n-i}\in F$. So $\langle x\rangle$ is closed under multiplication.

Is my test correct? Do you need something to conclude? Some help please.

Comment: At the end where you multiply two polynomials one of them should belong to ideal (summation index to start from 1) and other one should be any polynomial in the ring (summation index to begin with 0) and the final product should have constant term $0$ so that the product lies in the ideal.

Comment: I think other stuff is fine (ideal should be a subgroup with respect to addition).

Comment: to add to @ParamanandSingh's point, I have a few small comments. first, you write "Suppose $\langle x\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i$", but this equation does not make sense; the object on the left is a *subset* of $F\langle x\rangle$ and the object on the right is an *element* of $F\langle x\rangle$. what did you mean to write there instead? second, you then write "In fact, notice that $\langle x\rangle=\varnothing$", but this also does not make sense – $\langle x\rangle$ is certainly non-empty, as it contains (eg) the element $x$. what did you mean to write there instead?

Comment: these are fairly minor quibbles, but it's important to be precise with your language and to make sure you know *why* you are writing each sentence and *what* you want to say with it. otherwise though your proof looks good :)

Comment: Thanks to @AtticusStonestrom for attention to detail. I had just glossed over the post and found the more problematic part. But at this level (undergrad) it is absolutely important to be precise.

Comment: First of all, many thanks to both of you for correcting me, and helping me with the test. I had several typographical errors in writing such as $ \ langle x \ rangle = \ varnothing $, I meant that it is different from empty. And how I wrote the ideal, I also have an error, I wanted to write that the ideal is all polynomials with $ a_0 = 0 $ ... Thank you very much for the corrections. :) @AtticusStonestrom and Paramanand.